# How do I add colorbox-load classes and attributes to links that come from an svg image?

Tags: javascript, 9

I have SVG images that are added to nodes via [svg_image_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/svg_image_field) module. They have internal links in them `/load-parts-ajax/{nid}`. The path leads to a pop-up page view of content with this path `/load-parts-ajax/%`. I am attempting open the view in a colorbox. I have this in my implementation in Drupal 7, which works fine. We installled the colorbox_node module, and used the `colorbox-node` class and this was very easy.

For Drupal 9 however, I have colorbox installed, and it's library and have tried [colorbox_load](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_load), with [ng_lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/ng_lightbox), and I added the path to the allowed paths in the configuration with no dice. I am also trying to [colorbox_simple_load](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_simple_load) to call the `colorbox-load` class with no luck.

(I can hack render the whole view page site and all by stuffing `cboxElement` after the class but I am certain that is wrong.)

Here is the .js:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MY_MODULE = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        setTimeout(function () { //necessary to add a brief pause for colorbox to reintiate
          $(".view-MY-POP-UP-VIEW", context).once().flexslider({
            animation: "slides",
            slideshow: false,
            touch: false,
            animationLoop: false,
          });
        }, 500);
      });

      $(".field--name-field-MY-IMAGE .svg_a", context).each(function(index, item) {
        $(item).attr("href", $(item).attr("xlink:href"));
        $(item).attr("data-inner-width", "304");
        $(item).attr("data-inner-height", "532");
        $(item).attr("class", "colorbox-load");
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

And here is how I am calling my .js libraries, one where the SVG is rendered in a view, one for the node display.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function MY_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if (isset($view) && $view->storage->id() == 'MY_VIEW') {
    $view->element['#attached']['library'][] = 'MY_MODULE/MY-LIBRARY';
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function MY_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->bundle() == 'MY_NODE') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'MY_MODULE/MY-LIBRARY';
  }
}
```

The attributes from the .js file are getting added to the image links in both cases, but the `colorbox-load` class does not seem to get recognized as the links just open the view in a new window.

Here is the markup, which looks identical to the working drupal 7 markup (aside from using colorbox-load class instead of colorbox-node)

```
<a id="e3_hyperlink" xlink:title="" xlink:href="/load-parts-ajax/251" target="_blank" class="colorbox-load" href="/load-parts-ajax/251" data-inner-width="304" data-inner-height="532">
```

So before I wrongly open a bug report, is there something simple I am missing for implementing the `colorbox-load` class properly, or should something like this work just like it is?

**EDIT:**
The [colorbox_simple_load](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox_simple_load) has this in it's project page:

```
$url = Url::fromUri('internal:/example.html');
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('View'), $url);
$output = $link->toRenderable();
$output['#attributes']['class'] = [
  'colorbox-load',
];
colorbox_simple_load_page_attachments($output);
```

So I *could* put this in my custom module, but im not sure what sort of hook I would need to use to implement it on the SVG images.

Comment: My first thought is that it’s because you’re adding the color box classes and metadata via js.

Comment: Can you post an alternate solution?

Comment: Add the class and attributes to the links before they're rendered. (Don't use javascript to add them after the page has loaded.)

Comment: What is the best way to do that?

Comment: The links are on an svg image, so i don't think they are accessible to Drupal backend.

Comment: Ok, alternatively, I think you could try re-attaching behaviors, e.g. at the end of your behavior, run `Drupal.attachBehaviors('.field--name-field-MY-IMAGE')`. I think the issue is that colorbox has already looked for links with the colorbox class before you add the class to your links. Using Drupal.attachBehaviors should force colorbox to recheck your svg's links

Comment: classes were wrong,  will update the question 
`$(item).attr("class", "use-ajax");
 $(item).attr("data-dialog-type", "colorbox");`
should be used

Comment: Did you use `Drupal.attachBehaviors()`? or was this resolved in another way? Your last comment says you're going to update the question with some new javascript you tried, however I don't see it in the question.

Comment: I plan on posting what I did as an answer when I get time. I did add `Drupal.attachBehaviors()`, but I had to do that so the the classes would get added for anonymous users. The initial reason it wasn't working was that the classes I was using were not the proper classes to use alongside colorbox_load module.